# ELCB tripping often

Tags: electrical, lighting

who can I solve this problem of my three phase ELCB keeps tripping when power comes in,I have checked all possible earth leakage course but still it's tripping when main source of power comes. please help me

Comment: Is your 3 phase Wye or delta configuration. I have worked on Wye systems that had ground fault protection. One cause I found was a surge arestor (metal oxide varistors) had absorbed a big hit and was damaged causing enough leakage to trip the sensor.

Comment: Tripping safety devices are trying to tell you something is broke. Employ a reputable electrician to troubleshoot your problem.